# Postgres - could not determine which collation to use for string comparison

Tags: postgresql

I read up several web pages, all spoke about upgrading from Postgres pre-9.0 edition to post-9.1 edition.

> www.peterbe.com/plog/postgres-collation-citext-9.1
>   *servoytipsfromsovan.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/migrating-postgres-sql-from-v9-0-to-latest-version/*
>   nandovieira.com/using-insensitive-case-columns-in-postgresql-with-citext
>   *stackoverflow.com/questions/15981197/postgresql-error-type-citext-does-not-exist*
>   databasecm.blogspot.sg/2015/03/where-do-you-find-citext-module-in.html
>   *dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17609/how-do-i-resolve-postgresql-error-no-collation-was-derived-for-column-foo-w*

In my case, I upgraded from 9.4 to 9.5. The issue for me is, some database threw the error (as stated on the title) whenever I run a SELECT query yet some don't. I setup a separate test server with 9.4, the query runs well.

I do not need to compare case insensitive. In postgres 9.4, I did not load citext too. In fact all my string comparisons are to be case sensitive unless I use "ILIKE". I also loaded citext individually to ALL the databases in the server.

What information do I need to provide to you so that I can find out why some database works, some don't. And how do I solve the problem I encountered.

Comment: I think the problem has nothing to do with case sensitive vs. case insensitive. To find out where your problem lies, it would be important to know the failing query.

Comment: My query has union. I tried to run each subquery individually and there is no problem. When the join happened through union, it gives the error.

Comment: Two of the corresponding attributes on both sides on the `UNION`  in your query have a different collation, and PostgreSQL doesn't know how to compare them. Examine the attributes with `pg_collation_for()` and figure out which ones have different collation and why.

Comment: Ok i will try that. Actually the 8 tables are having same columns with same name. The reason why i need to do a union is because I need to merge the result of each subquery where each sum query do a filter based on the sum of the total value of a particular column.

Comment: Is there a way for me to see the collation as an overview instead of using pg_collation_for approach as I have 11 columns in each subquery? I am using EMS Postgres Manager

Comment: If it is collation problem, how is it possible i can run well in 9.4? Even when i reduce the join to just 2 tables, the error persist in 9.5 but 9.4 is okay. Both pg server are on Centos 6.5 x64

Comment: You'll have to do this on foot and find where the mismatch is. I don't know why it works in your 9.4 database - maybe some change in PostgreSQL, maybe you are using different collations there. Hard to tell without knowing more.

Comment: I checked all the affected tables (in my SQL) individually. Hard work... All have been set to en_US.UTF-8. 9.4 and 9.5 are both set using the same collation. Even the backup file are in the same encoding.

Comment: I installed 9.5 on windows, and the query ran just fine. Now i am really stuck.

Comment: Hm, I have no idea. Do the `EXPLAIN` plans look the same on both systems?